# pgfplots - legend displays incorrectly for stacked bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, legend, bar-chart

I have a problem with formatting the legend correctly. Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
x Order                               m0  m132  m3  m460  m6
0 gtx780-cb-s 0.57615 0.627627 0.394365 0.811266 1.05492
1 gtx780-mu-s 0.141668 0.315022 0.145579 0.202026 0.253015
4 gtx780-cb-d 3.784450 10.841200 5.527380 5.881210 8.342070
5 gtx780-mu-d 0.279953 0.918595 0.340272 0.471707 0.422749
8 k40-cb-s 0.695936 0.831193 0.476254 1.05996 1.26672
9 k40-mu-s 0.193261 0.434555 0.195305 0.303927 0.338011
12 k40-cb-d 1.004380 2.401120 1.314340 1.560650 2.067400
13 k40-mu-d 0.377453 1.200990 0.377581 0.598974 0.674917
}\datatable

\begin{axis}[
    x post scale=\linewidth/\axisdefaultwidth,
    xlabel=Time {[}ms{]},
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Order},
    xbar stacked,
    xmin=0,
    ymax=15,
    legend style={area legend,at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
]

\addplot table [x expr={4 * \thisrow{m0}}, y=x] {\datatable};
\addplot table [x=m132, y=x] {\datatable};
\addplot table [x=m3, y=x] {\datatable};
\addplot table [x=m460, y=x] {\datatable};
\addplot table [x=m6, y=x] {\datatable};

\addlegendimage{blue,sharp plot}
\addlegendimage{red,sharp plot}

\draw[blue] (axis cs:1.77394776117234,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:1.77394776117234,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax});
\draw[red] (axis cs:2.12873731340681,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:2.12873731340681,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax});

\legend{M0,M132,M3,M460,M6,line1,line2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
```

And the output I get is:
[image: screen]

As you can see the legend is not formatted nicely. I want little color areas for the bars and two lines for the two lines I've added to the plot. Also, how do I bring the lines on top of the bars?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for providing a MWE :) If you add `area style` to your `axis` then it seems to fix part of the issue...

Comment: Thank you @cmhughes! adding `line legend` to the extra legend entries did the trick. The only question I have left is how to bring the lines on top of the bars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As **cmhughes** mentioned in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170428/pgfplots-legend-displays-incorrectly-for-stacked-bar-chart/170439#comment392415_170428), adding the option `area style` to the `axis` environment gives the desired formatting for the legend.
2. Draw the lines before adding the plots.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
x Order                               m0  m132  m3  m460  m6
0 gtx780-cb-s 0.57615 0.627627 0.394365 0.811266 1.05492
1 gtx780-mu-s 0.141668 0.315022 0.145579 0.202026 0.253015
4 gtx780-cb-d 3.784450 10.841200 5.527380 5.881210 8.342070
5 gtx780-mu-d 0.279953 0.918595 0.340272 0.471707 0.422749
8 k40-cb-s 0.695936 0.831193 0.476254 1.05996 1.26672
9 k40-mu-s 0.193261 0.434555 0.195305 0.303927 0.338011
12 k40-cb-d 1.004380 2.401120 1.314340 1.560650 2.067400
13 k40-mu-d 0.377453 1.200990 0.377581 0.598974 0.674917
}\datatable

\begin{axis}[
    x post scale=\linewidth/\axisdefaultwidth,
    xlabel=Time {[}ms{]},
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Order},
    xbar stacked,
    xmin=0,
    ymax=15,
    area style,
    legend style={area legend,at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
]

\draw[blue] (axis cs:1.77394776117234,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:1.77394776117234,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax});
\draw[red] (axis cs:2.12873731340681,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:2.12873731340681,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax});

\addplot table [x expr={4 * \thisrow{m0}}, y=x] {\datatable};
\addplot table [x=m132, y=x] {\datatable};
\addplot table [x=m3, y=x] {\datatable};
\addplot table [x=m460, y=x] {\datatable};
\addplot table [x=m6, y=x] {\datatable};

\addlegendimage{blue,sharp plot}
\addlegendimage{red,sharp plot}


\legend{M0,M132,M3,M460,M6,line1,line2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]